# Sublime Text Does Not Let Me Save My Files

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

How do I fix this on Mac?

> Unable to save /test.py Error: Read-only file system

[image]

Comment: Had the same issue recently, after macOS Monterey v.12.4 update. And not just with sublime text, but also with Adobe Acrobat and other software. 

I was able to solve it by going to File > Save As and choosing "Desktop - iCloud" instead of "Macintosh HD". Thanks, u/Alec and u/Jeremy Caney

Answer (score 15):

Since Mojave, you are no longer allowed to write to `/`. I suspect this is the cause of your problem: nothing to do with Sublime Text.

Pick another directory to save your files to, preferably in your home folder.

Answer (score 6):

1. Once you make your document, go to <kbd>File</kbd> and click <kbd>Save</kbd> (or just press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>).
2. Write the title of your document.
3. Right under the name there should be a little box that says <kbd>Macintosh</kbd>. You can click on it and change it to whatever file you prefer.

Comment: So if you have your folder name on the clipboard, instead of saving with the filename `/x/y/z.txt`, you have to click the arrow next to Macintosh, hit Cmd+Shift+G, paste the folder path `/x/y`, then set the file name to `z.txt`. I miss Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

you must have left the save location as "macintosh". Basically this error means, that this "macintosh" folder is read-only. There is no issue like "sublime not having permission to write to the disk".

Just save to a usual folder and you would be gtg.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you save it to your project's folder and not just to the desktop or whatever is the default.